# Insert generates Binlog larger than the data

Tags: mysql

I try to migrate a 12GB table from node 1 to node 2. The migration generates almost 40GB binlog on node2. Why is the size of record 3 times larger than the data itself? This table comprises some empty columns filled with NULL, does this matter?

The MySQL version is 5.7. Any help is apprecited.

Comment: The `mysqldump` that you are importing, disable the binlog for the session you are importing the migration into node2 with.

Comment: Hi @danblack Thanks for your suggestion, it can help me finish migration without generating too much binlog. Would you mind to talk more about the binlog? All binlog is times larger than the data or some special stuff of the data may result in such large binlog?

Comment: I suspect there's other answers, here or https://dba.stackexchange.com/ that cover differences.